# REST: Securing public GET URL

Tags: rest, security

I have a `GET` url `http://ip.domain/api/items` to fetch data from the database and display it (pagination -- the users aren't logged in, else I'd have used a token). But the thing is, that It's public and anyone can use it. Is it possible to accept calls only from my domain? I completely understand that It's impossible to totally secure it. But just to make it a bit difficult for those who will try to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, add the following header to your script:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://ip.domain
```

*Set the domain to your actual domain.*

Here's a good article on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS